# Generate Pyramid Scheme code

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, parsing, lisp

[Pyramid Scheme](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/PyramidScheme) is a language being developed by [@ConorO'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien). In Pyramid Scheme, the code that you write looks like this:

```
      ^         ^
     / \       /3\
    /   \      ---
   /  +  \
  ^-------^
 /9\     /3\
/123\    ---
-----
```

Now, that code has two obvious qualities: It's difficult to parse, and it's difficult to write. Conor has solved the first one, however it will be your job to solve that second issue.

---

The above code is processed by the PyramidScheme interpreter into a nested string array, like this:

```
[["+", ["9123", "3"]], "3"]
```

Your task is to write a program or function, which given a nested array of strings, outputs or returns the recreated PyramidScheme code. You may assume that the input array will always be valid.

A pyramid is an isosceles triangle. The top is `^`, the sides slope diagonally away with `/` and `\`, and the bottom is `-`. The two bottom corners are either empty or contain the start of other pyramids, which are arguments. The middle is filled with the pyramid's name, ignoring line breaks.

Here's how the parser converts the code into a useable format. First, it scans for a top-level pyramid. If it takes no arguments, it represents it with a single string and moves on. Otherwise, it represents is as an array `["name",[arg1,arg2]]` or `["name",[arg1]]`. The arguments are the pyramids at the bottom left and bottom right of the pyramid, which may be either string or more arrays described as above. You may notice that this somewhat resembles Lisp, in which case you may also have noticed the awful pun that is the language name. After the pyramid is fully represented, the parser moves on to the next one.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code wins!

### Test Cases: These are not the only valid outputs, these are example of valid outputs.

```
[["+", ["9123", "3"]], "3"]

      ^         ^
     / \       /3\
    /   \      ---
   /  +  \
  ^-------^
 /9\     /3\
/123\    ---
-----
```

---

```
[["out", [["chr", ["72"]], ["chr", ["101"]]]], ["out", [["chr", ["108"]]]], ["out", [["chr", ["108"]]]], ["out", [["chr", ["111"]]]]]

        ^      ^     ^     ^
       / \    / \   / \   / \
      /out\  /out\ /out\ /out\
     ^-----^ -----^----- -----^
    / \   / \    / \         / \
   /chr\ /chr\  /chr\       /chr\
  ^----- -----^ -----^     ^-----
 / \         / \    / \   / \
/72 \       /101\  /108\ /111\
-----       -----  ----- -----
```

---

```
[ ["+", [ ["asdfghjkl"], ["do", [ "1" ]] ]] ]

       ^
      / \
     / + \
    /     \
   ^-------^
  /a\     /d\
 /sdf\   /o  \
/ghjkl\ ^-----
-------/1\
       ---
```

Notice in the second test case, the second and third `out` pyramid both have a `["chr", ["108"]]` as a parameter, which is collapsed into one pyramid stack shared by two top-level ones. This is a valid optimization your code may support, but it is completely optional; scoring is not based on the length of your output.

For the curious, the first case displays `9126 3` due to implicit printing of toplevel pyramids, the second one prints `Hello`, and the last one is a syntax error, included just because it has a neat structure.

---

You may assume that the input only contains printable ASCII, excluding spaces, `^`, `/`, `\`, and `-`. The input will always be valid, and contain at least one pyramid. There is no limit on the size of the array or the input strings, however you may write your code as if your language's default integer type was infinite precision and that your computer has arbitrary memory. If taking input as a single string, you may use anything reasonable (comma, space, etc. as long as it's in printable ascii and not `"` or `[]`) to delimit arrays. You do not have to include brackets surrounding the entire thing, and instead take multiple arrays separated by your delimiter.

Your output does not have to be golfed, you may insert extra space or make your pyramids larger than necessary. Toplevel pyramids *should* be on the first line. Output should be a string with newlines or a list of strings.

Anyone who *does* include a version of their code which optimally golfs the pyramids may receive some rep in the form of upvotes/bounties (but probably just upvotes).

Comment: Sierpinski would love this language.

Comment: Totally didn't post this challenge because I'm too lazy to format triangles properly...

Comment: @KodosJohnson Input can be a native array.

Comment: how can you have a function with more than two arguments?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon The input will never contain an array such that it will require passing two arguments to a pyramid, as this is impossible in Pyramid Scheme.

Comment: huh, so it is actually rather different than lisp aside from ascii art syntax.

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Not really, Lisp lists with more than two elements are actually stored internally as `(a (b ( c (d))))`, and Pyramid Lisp has a function which takes two args and returns them as a lsit iirc. (Everything I just said might be wrong)

Comment: This is a challenge that I will love to see some good answers for.

Comment: Just to recap: the top level array can have any number of elements, while the subarrays will only have 1 or 2. Right?

Comment: @edc65 correct.

Comment: Since you said that top-level pyramids ***should*** be on the first line, does that mean they don't have to be? I mean, could each pyramid be placed under the preceding pyramid?

Comment: @KodosJohnson No, they have to be on the first line.

Comment: @Pavel, I understand how linked lists work, you know. I think the function you refer to would be cons? If that were the case eval would also be needed I believe

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon I know neither how normal Lisp works, nor how Pyramid Scheme works. I *think* PS has those functions, but there's not actually a documentation; everything I know comes from reading the interpreter's source.

Comment: How should it behave if a string is something like "[\"]"

Comment: @LliwTelracs No need to escape characters. If you want to, you may support that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Common Lisp - <s>2524</s> 1890 bytes

```lisp
(defun f(i)(let((s(loop as r in i collect(g r)))(n())(output""))(loop until n do(setf n T)(loop as r in s do(if(cdr r)(progn(setf output(c output(e r))(cdr r)(cdr(cdr r)))(setf n()))(setf output(c output(b(car r))))))(setf output(c output(format()"~%"))))output))(defun g(r)(if(stringp r)(d(m(length r))r)(if(<(length r)2)(d(m(length(car r)))(car r))(if(=(length(e r))1)(let((h(g(car(e r))))(p(d(m(length(car r)))(car r))))(let((o(+ 1(position #\^(e h))))(parent_length(car p)))(if(<(-(car h)o)parent_length)(l(cons(+ o parent_length)())(loop as n in(butlast(cdr p))collect(c(b o)n))(cons(c(subseq(e h)0 o)(car(last p)))())(loop as n in(cdr(cdr h))collect(c n(b (- parent_length(-(car h)o))))))(let((i(-(- o 1)parent_length)))(l(cons(car h)())(loop as n in(butlast(cdr p))collect(c(b o)n(b i)))(cons(c(subseq(nth 1 h)0 o)(car(last p))(b i))())(cddr h))))))(let((l-h(g(car(e r))))(r-h(g(e(e r)))))(let((ll(position #\^(e l-h)))(rl(position #\^(e r-h))))(let((lr(-(car l-h)ll 1))(rr(-(car r-h)rl 1)))(let((p(d(max(m(length(car r)))(ceiling(+ lr rl)2))(car r))))(let((m-pad(if(>(car p)(+ lr rl))(-(car p)lr rl)0)))(l(cons(+ ll 1(car p)1 rr)())(loop as n in(butlast(cdr p))collect(c(b(+ 1 ll))n(b(+ 1 rr))))(cons(c(subseq(e l-h)0(+ 1 ll))(car(last p))(subseq(e r-h)rl))())(loop as y in(append(cddr l-h)(make-list(length l-h):initial-element(b(car l-h))))as z in(append(cdr(cdr r-h))(make-list(length r-h):initial-element(b(car r-h))))collect(c y(b m-pad)z))))))))))))(defun d(r n)(cons(+(* 2 r)1)(l(cons(c(b r)"^"(b r))())(loop as i from 1 to r collect(c(b(- r i))"/"(subseq(c n(b(expt i 2)))(expt(- i 1)2)(expt i 2))"\\"(b(- r i))))(cons(make-string(+ 1(* 2 r)):initial-element #\-)()))))(defun m(l)(+ 1(floor(sqrt l))))(defun b(n)(make-string n :initial-element #\space))(defun c(&rest a)(apply 'concatenate 'string a))(defun l(&rest a)(apply 'concatenate 'list a))(defun e(tree)(nth 1 tree))
```

Thanks to @coredump for a number of golfing tricks.  Sample output from the question:

```
> (f '(("out" (("chr" ("72")) ("chr" ("101")))) ("out" (("chr" ("108")))) ("out" (("chr" ("108")))) ("out" (("chr" ("111"))))))
          ^               ^          ^          ^  
         /o\             /o\        /o\        /o\ 
        /ut \           /ut \      /ut \      /ut \
       /     \         ^-----     ^-----     ^-----
      /       \       /c\        /c\        /c\    
     ^---------^     /hr \      /hr \      /hr \   
    /c\       /c\   ^-----     ^-----     ^-----   
   /hr \     /hr \ /1\        /1\        /1\       
  ^-----    ^-----/08 \      /08 \      /11 \      
 /7\       /1\    -----      -----      -----      
/2  \     /01 \                                    
-----     -----                                    










> (f '( ("+" ( ("asdfghjkl") ("do" ( "1" )) )) ))
          ^        
         /+\       
        /   \      
       /     \     
      /       \    
     /         \   
    ^-----------^  
   /a\         /d\ 
  /sdf\       /o  \
 /ghjkl\     ^-----
/       \   /1\    
---------  /   \   
           -----   








> (f '(("+" ("9123" "3")) "3"))
       ^        ^  
      /+\      /3\ 
     /   \    /   \
    /     \   -----
   ^-------^       
  /9\     /3\      
 /123\   /   \     
/     \  -----     
-------
```

Here is the original, (mostly) ungolfed version:

```lisp
(defun f (input)
    (let ((trees (loop for tree in input collect (g tree)))
          (done nil)
          (output ""))
        (loop while (not done)
            do  (setf done T) 
                (loop for tree in trees
                    do  (if (cdr tree)
                            (progn
                                (setf output (conStr output (car (cdr tree))))
                                (setf (cdr tree) (cdr (cdr tree)))
                                (setf done nil))
                            (setf output (conStr output (blank (car tree))))))
                (setf output (conStr output  (format nil "~%"))))
        output))

;creates a single tree
;output is a list, first element is the length of each line, the rest are the lines of text
(defun g (tree)
    (if (stringp tree)
        ;strings should be drawn as just the pyramid for the name
        (draw-body (min-rows (length tree)) tree)

        (if (< (length tree) 2)
            ;lists with no arguments should be drawn as just the pyramid for the name
            (draw-body (min-rows (length (car tree))) (car tree))
            (if (= (length (car (cdr tree))) 1)
                ;single child
                (let ((child (g (car (car (cdr tree))))) (parent (draw-body (min-rows (length (car tree))) (car tree))))
                    (let ((parent_offset (+ 1 (position #\^ (first-line child)))) (parent_length (car parent)))
                        (if (< (- (car child) parent_offset) parent_length)
                            (let ((child-fill (- parent_length (- (car child) parent_offset))))
                                (concatenate 'list 
                                    (cons (+ parent_offset parent_length) nil)
                                    (loop for line in (butlast (cdr parent))
                                        collect (conStr (blank parent_offset) line))
                                    (cons (conStr (subseq (nth 1 child) 0 parent_offset) (car (last parent))) nil)
                                    (loop for line in (cdr (cdr child))
                                        collect (conStr line (blank child-fill)))))
                            (let ((parent-fill (- (- parent_offset 1) parent_length)))
                                (concatenate 'list 
                                    (cons (car child) nil)
                                    (loop for line in (butlast (cdr parent))
                                        collect (conStr (blank parent_offset) line (blank parent-fill)))
                                    (cons (conStr (subseq (nth 1 child) 0 parent_offset) (car (last parent)) (blank parent-fill)) nil)
                                    (cdr (cdr child)))))))
                ;two children
                (let ((l-child (g (car (car (cdr tree))))) (r-child (g (car (cdr (car (cdr tree)))))))
                    (let ((lc-l-width (position #\^ (first-line l-child))) (rc-l-width (position #\^ (first-line r-child))))
                        (let ((lc-r-width (- (car l-child) lc-l-width 1)) (rc-r-width (- (car r-child) rc-l-width 1)))
                            (let ((parent (draw-body (max (min-rows (length (car tree))) (ceiling (+ lc-r-width rc-l-width) 2)) (car tree))))
                                (let ((m-pad (if (> (car parent) (+ lc-r-width rc-l-width))
                                            (- (car parent) lc-r-width rc-l-width)
                                            0)))
                                    (concatenate 'list
                                        (cons (+ lc-l-width 1 (car parent) 1 rc-r-width) nil)
                                        (loop for line in (butlast (cdr parent))
                                            collect (conStr (blank (+ 1 lc-l-width)) line (blank (+ 1 rc-r-width))))
                                        (cons (conStr (subseq (first-line l-child) 0 (+ 1 lc-l-width)) (car (last parent)) (subseq (first-line r-child) rc-l-width)) nil)
                                        (loop for left in (append (cdr (cdr l-child)) (make-list (length l-child) :initial-element (blank (car l-child))))
                                            for right in (append (cdr (cdr r-child)) (make-list (length r-child) :initial-element (blank (car r-child))))
                                            collect (conStr left (blank m-pad) right))))))))))))


;create a single pyramid
; output is a list, first element is the length of each line, the rest are the lines of text
(defun draw-body (rows name)
    (print rows)
    (print name)
    (cons (+ (* 2 rows) 1)
        (concatenate 'list (cons (conStr (blank rows) "^" (blank rows)) nil)
            (loop for i from 1 to rows
                collect (conStr (blank (- rows i)) "/" (subseq (conStr name (blank (expt i 2))) (expt (- i 1) 2) (expt i 2)) "\\" (blank (- rows i))))
            (cons (make-string (+ 1 (* 2 rows)) :initial-element #\-) nil))))

(defun min-rows (l)
    (+ 1 (floor (sqrt l))))

(defun blank (n)
    (make-string n :initial-element #\space))

(defun conStr (&rest args)
    (apply 'concatenate 'string args))

(defun first-line (tree)
    (car (cdr tree)))
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/clisp#xVXLbtswELznKwgWbXYbCLWcQx9o@xU9BilkibLV0KRC0UCSQ349HT4ky3YSIECBGolE7c4O9zGinqhR7c6IljomrTzRQNraXlSDcKIzohO11VrVntbCMTMZwsXufL/zUmIZ0TvjOy2MaCwNyrdY/eJDniH4upbqxoGHemfXJmETF9XjQoV9RhxueQlboqZpeRy5orpK0BchrXXbyhPLx/cyoJIZ6NSGNWFPZDl415l1HzJoaIvGmLXfBObk/r63LOeIaf9xEcA/RmcsrMxt3tA6gJIRwP41Gs5Bli5ESb0dOt9ZI95dXSN@k@Irp4z/PSPomXOyRXzesOUDFEiptmYAqRVHHt6PDxowtNp5XQ0@zgLEoyZqWgnLJmQaiGoadqtB3casFvDEEkNgyuaYdZzuZsaIAa8EFYcJzUrgfTs6mAvkXh7VxVNlKeiN1eDa8UlJBuMunysrwSlqNtWyz1AXx3N20aLG5xGnj6eKyAg/cbhiM4tzuTMBrjU6gZDRFpAu2jI6aqy6e05nqtMQPJSgYdFQ9Yn2tkVfNUFPP7O6JjDn/XpOz4vZAIBBBtldCufeMoygdsRzGElcu5TPsdZC8YsJfDicCZS6cSjC@7B/1ffKNGl4gQktulGF7pBSfsuD9VtnMIVKF0qrLbSWD5s0JgbXwwFXPrWC95TPvcyXp7t/G@4hr9h6fuDZL59XDTlhckMu6KNYYmLlXv2IdSyvZbwfVN6J1tktOuYtzud5z4twXjPLT3LsXXwlSd31HmHLsHlYA9hBW0ueeeTVldxTjJOK9acTNZ5fKc2TDkDfRchxXx10yjGiRdqOhlvnhZ75V2R4zg49PUM69FWtppiaPjgFbVQchqXvxTlyrCuvDP7FeSaqJrx@HR/GOkMr8k4pzodFXPNT/ugIL@RjIwW14pxI4suDNcl643CXn5f4HonpsVyU8fskToDl4svbPWViw@/sKBtZ/OPfmTzZI1aMNC6wxK0amna9@XOjZUi1scEqSymQefz7fzmmFOXXcnmJXS/DROKVn/4C)

Comment: You should be able to golf off a lot of bytes by removing unnecessary spaces.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG and nice first answer!

Comment: Some tips for golfing CL: in loops, "for" can also be written "as"; you can remove spaces before and after parentheses and double-quotes; you can replace NIL by `()`; you can also use reader variables, sometimes

Comment: ... `loop while (not x)` is `loop until x`, `(cdr (cdr x))` is `(cddr x)`, `(setf a b c d)` is shorter than `(setf a b)` followed by `(setf c d)`, etc. But this is already a good answer

Comment: Azor1 holy cow! Nice job. If nobody answers then you will get a 50 rep bounty from me. Try and golf as much as you can!

Comment: I don't know common lisp, so maybe I'm doing it wrong, but it seems to be off a little: https://gist.github.com/pavelyay/dd7eea5c0dc8713b1327608ab9e780f7 (The link is in the gist, it's too long to fit in a comment)

Comment: try using `(format t "~d" ___)` instead of `(print ___)`. I think `print` outputs the text as lisp code, so the quotes are present and the backslashes need escaping whereas `format` prints the actual content.

Comment: In addition to the +50 bounty, the fact that you posted this *amazing* answer will get another bounty from me.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere you being for real? If so that is pretty cool

Comment: @ChristopherPeart Depending on what happens the next 2 days, I was thinking +200-+300. This is a very challenging problem.

Comment: You wrote `(cdr(cdr r))`. Isn't `(cddr r)` same thing but shorter?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere yeah I took one look and started nopeing out. It is a cool problem and deserves a lot of rep.

Comment: @PrzemysławP yea it is, I must have missed it when I was golfing

Comment: @Azor1 congratz! +50 rep

Comment: A total bounty of 350 reputation is significant... but this answer deserves it. A Common Lisp answer to a question about constructing questions for a Lisp dialect... Wow.

Comment: This is kinda late, but I found three `(cdr(cdr ...))`s in your code.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp They are present in the ungolfed code, but the golfed code uses `cddr`.

Comment: @Phoenix There are still `(cdr(cdr t))` in the golfed code.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp Huh, I'm blind then, I went threw it a couple times yesterday...

Answer (score 10):

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), ~41.3KB + tests and examples

So, I didn't realise this was a challenge, and I wrote a whole language which compiles into Pyramid scheme...  It's called psll, and you can find it [here](https://github.com/MarcinKonowalczyk/psll-lang). It has a bunch of bells and whistles, syntactic sugar constructs: functions (kinda) and strings, compiler optimisation etc.

This is not exactly a competing answer, but I feel it's heavily relevant so I should post it here.